# Is there a listener as you draw with drawingTools?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The drawingTools have the onDraw listener which fires after a shape is drawn.

I was wondering if there is a way to listen WHILE a shape is being drawn (e.g. as you click each vertex in a polygon or linestring).  This would be useful if you want to see the coordinates of each vertex you click, if you wanted to measure the distance from the last vertex to the next vertex you are about the create, etc.